# Why does my division operator keep returning a zero?

Tags: ruby, random, division

When I print the result of "chances" it keeps returning a value of "0".  I am not sure if it has to do with me using the rand operator.  How can I fix this so it will return its actual value instead of 0?

```
    p1Health = rand(50..100).to_i
    p1Attack = rand(25..50).to_i
    p1Overall = (p1Health + p1Attack).to_i

    p2Health = rand(50..100).to_i
    p2Attack = rand(25..50).to_i
    p2Overall = (p2Health + p2Attack).to_i

    p1p2 = p1Overall + p2Overall

    chances = p1Overall / (p1Overall + p2Overall)
```

Comment: Remember in Ruby that capital letters have specific meaning, so variable and method names should be lower-case only. Consider using names like `p1_health` or, even better `player[0][:health]` by using proper data structures here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calculating `chances` you're doing integer division, which will return a result rounded down to the nearest integer. In this case, you're seeing `0` because your result is meant to be a percentage (since it's less than 1, it rounds down to 0 in integer division).

To return the actual value you'll want to convert one of the integers to a `Float`, like so:

```
chances = p1Overall / (p1Overall + p2Overall).to_f
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: That did it, thanks!

Comment: There's also the little known / rarely used / often overlooked [`fdiv`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Float.html#method-i-fdiv), e.g. `p1overall.fdiv(p1overall + p2overall)`

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby an integer divided by an integer yields an integer result. That is:

```
1 / 2
# => 0
```

Where `0` is the closest integer answer to that. What's different is:

```
5 / 2
# => 2
```

Where that's basically 2.5 rounded down to 2.

If you want a floating-point result:

```
chances = p1overall.to_f / (p1overall + p2overall)
```

Where that `.to_f` coverts to floating-point first. That yields a floating-point answer as a result.

Answer (score 1):

In Most language(c,c++, java,ruby, python ..etc) `integer/integer` yields `integer` result.
you have to use at least one value to be the float.

that's the basic convention used by many languages:

The operation performs on:

```
integer + integer => integer
integer - integer => integer
integer / integer => integer
integer * integer => integer  
float + integer => float
integer + float => float
float / integer => float
integer / float => float
```

Comment: In Smalltalk, `1/3` returns `(1/3)`, i.e. an instance of `Fraction`, the pendant to Ruby's `Rational`.

Comment: Thank @Stefan for correcting me, have updated the post `plus one`